# page not found 404 when trying to save in django

Tags: django

can anyone help me on my problem, when trying to save my page get an error 404. here is the coding

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^$', PatientView.as_view()),
(r'^patientList/$', PatientView.as_view(), name ="forside"),
(r'^rehab_diab/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RehabDiabetesView.as_view(), name="rehabDiabetes_view"),
```

views.py

```
class RehabDiabetesView(UpdateView):
template_name="rehab_diab.html"
model = RehabDiabetes
form_class = RehabDiabetesForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(RehabDiabetesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['pk']=self.kwargs['pk']
    return context

def get_object(self, queryset = None):
    try: 
        obj = RehabDiabetes.objects.get(owner = Patient.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk']))
    except: 
        obj = RehabDiabetes.objects.create(owner = Patient.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk']))
    return obj

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("forside"))
```

rehab_diab.html

```
<form id="content" action="rehabDiabetes_view pk" method="POST" style="opacity: 1; ">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Gem" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
```

-------#rest of the code..

and here is the error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http:xxx.xxx.xxx/rehab_diab/1/rehabDiabetes_view%20pk
Using the URLconf defined in rehab3.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
^patientList/$ [name='forside']
^rehab_diab/(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='rehabDiabetes_view']
The current URL, rehab_diab/1/rehabDiabetes_view pk, didn't match any of these.
```

what is the missing link?? can't figure it out since im newbies in django..:(
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `action="{% url rehabDiabetes_view pk %}"`?

Comment: yes thank you Daniel Roseman...i did change it and now it didn't give me any error..great:)..really appreciate it..